# error in zend framework model creation

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am just started using zend framework. i created a project in zend

structure

```
 application
     configs
         application.ini
     layouts
     modules
         core
           DB
             Dbclass.php
           Table
         default
           controllers
           views
           forms
     bootstrap.php
 library
 public
 index
```

my bootstrap file contain

```
 public function _autoload(){

    set_include_path(
    '/application/modules/core/DB' 
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . 
    '/application/modules/core/Table' 
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . 
    get_include_path());
}
public function _init(){

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->setControllerDirectory(array(
    'default' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default/controllers'
    ));
}
```

my application.ini file contain

```
 [production]
 phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
 phpSettings.display_errors = 0
 phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
 ;includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
 bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
 bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
 appnamespace = "Application"
 ;resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
 resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
 resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH   "/modules/controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
```

when i create a object in indexcontroller

```
 $new_object = new Dbclass();
```

there is an error showing that

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Dbclass' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\pubman\application\modules\default\controllers\IndexController.php on line 16
```

if any one know this please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you start with ZF2 instead of ZF1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments/observations:

1. You method `Bootstrap::_autoload()` will not run. Bootstrap will automatically run all methods of the form `_initXXX()`.
2. Typically, you would not put the models in `modules/core/DB/*`. You would put them in `modules/core/models/*` The default resource autoloader knows to look for them there.
3. You are specifying the appnamespace `Application_`. That means that all the classes inside directories like `application/models`, `application/services`, `application/forms`, etc would be named in the form `Application_Model_Something`, not just `Something` as you have. But since you have placed these classes inside the core module, they would be named something like `Core_Model_Something`.
4. If you want to use modules, then you should have a `resources.modules[] =` declaration in your `application/configs/application.ini`
5. You would typically have a Bootstrap class for each module - named, for exmaple, `Core_Bootstrap` - extending `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`. This will ensure the standard resource autoloader for the module gets invoked.

This should get you closer. Frankly, there are a lot of things going on there, so this is unlikely to be a complete list. The essential part is to understand what the system would need to know in order to load a class that is not on the `include_path` (like models, forms, etc): a namespace prefix, a base path at which it needs to start performing its PSR-0 construction.